# Can I have two routes that are complimentary to each other?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can I have these two routes defined? I tried this example but got a 404.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ActionFirst",
    url: "{action}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And the following controllers and actions:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Hello, World!");
    }

    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return Content("I am the Foo action on the Home controller");
    }
}
```

The following Urls that conform to the *Default* route work:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/
http://localhost:xxxx/Home
http://localhost:xxxx/Home/Foo
```

But the ones that conform to the *ActionFirst* route name, as listed below, do not:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/Foo
http://localhost:xxxx/Foo/Home
```

I was hoping that the ASP.NET Routing engine would try the Url against all routes if the route failed against one of them.

So if the url failed to match the first route name, it would try matching it against the second. But that doesn't appear to be the case.

Of course, if I remove the *Default* route and have just the *ActionFirst* route, then the second lot of Urls do work.

Comment: Put your specific route before the default route.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** No

**Slightly less short answer:** It won't try one route and then the next, it just finds the first *matching* route from top to bottom. In your example, whichever route was defined first will win.

**What you *can* do** (and perhaps what you were intending?) [untested]

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeActions",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Now you'll get the following routed to your `HomeController`

```
http://yoursite.com/
http://yoursite.com/Foo
http://yoursite.com/Foo/123
```

And the following routed to a `OtherController`

```
http://yoursite.com/Other/Foo
http://yoursite.com/Other/Foo/123
```